# XCode Archive: "you must supply an apple ID"

Tags: xcode5

When I Archive a applicaion. Xcode message:

The following issue were found validation: "You must supply an apple ID",.

Where I could write down an **apple ID** ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I got same problem. just solve it. I guess this is because xcode 5 is not proper functioning with apple server for validation.

Very simple to do. ignore the validation, just click distribute to app store, it will do validation as well. I got no issue and upload to itunes connect.

Comment: Your are right. Update to xcode6, no this error msg.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have entered your apple ID info in the **Xcode->Preferences->Accounts** tab. By apple ID they mean the ID which you use to log into developer.apple.com, the member center, or your iTunes account (assuming you are a registered developer).

If you are not a registered developer you can go to http://developer.apple.com and click on the **Member Center** (upper left on the website) then the **Register** link to register your apple ID as a developer ID (this is free).

Comment: I have write down a right account, but in the last step of validation report a error: "You must supply an apple ID".

Comment: thanks, but I have a developer account. Just in validation error.

Comment: When you open Xcode, and you look at the Preferences by clicking Xcode -> Preferences on the Menu Bar at the top of the screen there is a tab called Accounts. Enter your Apple ID info on this page (Xcode will store that info there and use it when you archive or submit to the app-store etc...)